Find all continuous, monotonic functions $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ that $f(xf(y)) + f(yf(x)) = 1 + f(x + y)$

Find all continuous, monotonic functions $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ that $f(xf(y)) + f(yf(x)) = 1 + f(x + y)$

The case where $f$ is monotonic non-decreasing and the case where exist $x$ such that $f(x) = 1$ all lead to $f(x) = 1$ for all $x$.
The case where $f$ is non-decreasing and $f(x)<1$ for all $x$ is less than trivial, I've guessed that the answer is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$ but it's hard to prove.

This is the B6 of 2022 Putnam Problems.
You can find the solution here:
https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2022s.pdf
Another references:

Functional equation $f(xf(y)) + f(yf(x)) = 1 + f(x + y) \space$ [B6 Putnam $2022$]

